# How to get CMS page content in JS in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, html, cms-pages, page-builder

I am using page builder to create cms pages. I require to have a preview button on the cms page. after clicking preview, we store the cms page form data in a separate table. I added one template file in the cms page to call the js code

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'underscore',
        'mage/template'
    ], function($){
        $(document).ready(function() {
            console.log('here-devidas');
            $(document).on('click','#preview',function() {
                        console.log('here-preview');
                        var customurl = "<?php echo $this->getUrl().'sectiontype/managesection/preview'?>";
                        //var title = $('[name=title]').val();
                        var title = $("input[name=title]").val();
                        var content_heading = $("input[name=content_heading]").val();
                        var content = $("input[name=content]").val();

                        console.log(title);
                        console.log(content_heading);
                        console.log(content);

                        /*$.ajax({
                            type : 'POST',
                            url : customurl,
                            data: ({
                            title: title,
                            content_heading: content_heading
                            }),
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function(response){                                
                        }
                        });*/
                    });
        } );
    })
</script>
```

button

[image]

I am getting another field data but am unable to get page builder content field data in jQuery.

can anyone help how to get content HTML data in jQuery?

pagebuilder store data in HTML format.